# WxPython import widgets from other classes

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm a beginner in WxPython and I've tried experimenting splitting up the code to make it organized and look neater. I've tried it with simple code but it doesn't work. Can anyone please give me a hand?

**The code I've tried:**

```
import wx

class text_ctrl ( wx.Panel ):
    def __init ( self, parent ):
        wx.Panel.__init__ ( self, parent = parent )
        text = wx.TextCtrl ( self, pos = ( 100, 100 ) )

class Window ( wx.Frame ):
    def __init__ ( self ):
        super().__init__ ( parent = None, title = "Learn - Tab TextBox" )
        
        panel = wx.Panel()
        
        text_ctrl ( self )
        
        self.Show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    window = Window()
    app.MainLoop()
```

**Problem:** Textbox doesn't show up ( which is supposed to be the main point ).

Comment: To organise code see[this answer] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/45555968/3070181)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For want of a nail the kingdom was lost

You are missing a `__`
Without the `init`, nothing occurs when you call `text_ctrl`

```
import wx

class text_ctrl ( wx.Panel ):
    #def __init ( self, parent ):
    def __init__ ( self, parent ):
        wx.Panel.__init__ ( self, parent = parent )
        text = wx.TextCtrl ( self, pos = ( 100, 100 ) )

class Window ( wx.Frame ):
    def __init__ ( self ):
        super().__init__ ( parent = None, title = "Learn - Tab TextBox" )
        
       # panel = wx.Panel()
        
        text_ctrl ( self )
        
        self.Show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    window = Window()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Comment: Lol that was silly of me, thanks!