# how to modularise code for wxpython project

Tags: wxpython, modularity

i am trying to modularise my code. below is the code generated from wxformbuilder..

```
class MyFrame ( wx.Frame ):

    def __init__( self, parent ):
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 776,483 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )

        self.SetSizeHints( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )

        self.m_menubar1 = wx.MenuBar( 0 )
        self.m_menu1 = wx.Menu()
        self.m_menubar1.Append( self.m_menu1, u"MyMenu" )

        self.m_menu2 = wx.Menu()
        self.m_menubar1.Append( self.m_menu2, u"MyMenu2" )

        self.m_menu3 = wx.Menu()
        self.m_menubar1.Append( self.m_menu3, u"MyMenu3" )

        self.SetMenuBar( self.m_menubar1 )

        bSizer4 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.HORIZONTAL )

        self.splitter_window = wx.SplitterWindow( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.SP_3DBORDER )
        self.splitter_window.Bind( wx.EVT_IDLE, self.splitter_windowOnIdle )

        self.left_window = wx.Panel( self.splitter_window, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
        self.right_window = wx.Panel( self.splitter_window, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
        bSizer5 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

        self.m_notebook2 = wx.Notebook( self.right_window, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.left_panel = wx.Panel( self.m_notebook2, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
        self.m_notebook2.AddPage( self.left_panel, u"a page", False )
        self.right_panel = wx.Panel( self.m_notebook2, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
        self.m_notebook2.AddPage( self.right_panel, u"a page", False )

        bSizer5.Add( self.m_notebook2, 1, wx.EXPAND |wx.ALL, 5 )


        self.right_window.SetSizer( bSizer5 )
        self.right_window.Layout()
        bSizer5.Fit( self.right_window )
        self.splitter_window.SplitVertically( self.left_window, self.right_window, 200 )
        bSizer4.Add( self.splitter_window, 1, wx.EXPAND, 5 )


        self.SetSizer( bSizer4 )
        self.Layout()

        self.Centre( wx.BOTH )

    def __del__( self ):
        pass

    def splitter_windowOnIdle( self, event ):
        self.splitter_window.SetSashPosition( 200 )
        self.splitter_window.Unbind( wx.EVT_IDLE )
```

and this is the way am trying to create separate classes for each panels and windows

```
import wx
import wx.lib.inspection

class l_window(wx.Panel):
    def __init__( self , parent):
        super().__init__(self, parent)

        left_window = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )

class r_window(wx.Panel):
    def __init__( self , parent):
        super().__init__(self, parent)

        self.right_window = wx.Panel( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )

        bSizer5 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )
        self.m_notebook2 = wx.Notebook( self.right_window, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.left_panel = wx.Panel( self.m_notebook2, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
        self.m_notebook2.AddPage( self.left_panel, u"a page", False )
        self.right_panel = wx.Panel( self.m_notebook2, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
        self.m_notebook2.AddPage( self.right_panel, u"a2 page", False )

        bSizer5.Add( self.m_notebook2, 1, wx.EXPAND |wx.ALL, 5 )

class menu_( wx.Menu ):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        
        self.m_menubar1 = wx.MenuBar( 0 )
        self.m_menu1 = wx.Menu()
        self.m_menubar1.Append( self.m_menu1, u"MyMenu" )

        self.m_menu2 = wx.Menu()
        self.m_menubar1.Append( self.m_menu2, u"MyMenu2" )

        self.m_menu3 = wx.Menu()
        self.m_menubar1.Append( self.m_menu3, u"MyMenu3" )

class MyFrame( wx.Frame ):
    def __init__( self, parent ):
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, 
                id = wx.ID_ANY, 
                title = wx.EmptyString, 
                pos = wx.DefaultPosition, 
                size = wx.Size( 900,600 ), 
                style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )

        self.SetMenuBar( menu_ )

        bSizer4 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.HORIZONTAL )

        self.splitter_window = wx.SplitterWindow( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.SP_3D )
        l1 = l_window(self.splitter_window)
        r1 = r_window(self.splitter_window)
        self.splitter_window.SplitVertically(l1, r1, 200)
        bSizer4.Add( self.splitter_window, 1, wx.EXPAND, 5 )
        self.SetSizer( bSizer4 )

app = wx.App()
frame = MyFrame(parent=None)
frame.Show()
wx.lib.inspection.InspectionTool().Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

this has produced me so many errors on different combinations i tried...

goal here is to factor code of gui segments, in its own different classes(that can be put in different files altogether) for long term manageability.

Layout is : top Frame has menu bar, also boxsizer that contains splitterwindow, splitterwindow has 2 panes left_window and right_window. right pane consist a notebook with two panels inside.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After using wxPython for just a short time I learned that structure was vital to enable you to code  and maintain efficiently. For small apps a single file with multiple classes will suffice, but as the controls and/or panels and dialogs increase then organising the code in separate files becomes indispensible

A similar question has been asked and answered before ([Confused on how to structure the GUI (wxpython)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6133348/confused-on-how-to-structure-the-gui-wxpython/54649692#54649692))

In one answer I show how the code can be organised into 4 files, for example

1. the main frame for the application and the application loader;
2. main_panel.py: the main panel for the application;
3. menu_bar.py: the menu bar definition for the frame;
4. tool_bar.py: the tool bar from the frame.

Comment: thank you.. i got it woking by splittting code in 4 files as well ..  looks good for maintainenece. i have further qs.. in my right window file ``` class r_window(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super(r_window, self).__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs) ```  why is super have 2 mentions of parent class.. we are supplying parent in init method right? and why super is not empty?

Comment: Just a hangover from Python 2. Super can be empty as you suggest